AGP How to use different versions of library
I have few feature modules. I need to use different version of one library in each module.
For example firebase-auth but it can be any dependency.
rootProject :app
|    project :feature1
|    |    +--- com.google.firebase:firebase-auth:22.0.0
|    project :feature2
|    |    +--- com.google.firebase:firebase-auth:23.0.0

Something like this.
I read about resolving dependency on Gradle. Also I found old andswers but they don't work.
I tried to create new configuration and provide dependency with it.
All solutions works for root gradle project. But particular project get only transitive dependencies and works with it or it gets force or scrict versions from app project. Any one knows how to resolve it? Please

You cannot do this: there can only be one version
